# Sudden slow-down of query, when requested from specific process only

Tags: sql-server

We are experiening a recuring phenomenon (around 2-3 times a month), where a client is requesting a service, and the process running this service is taking too long too respond. Normal response time is 1 second, but whenever this happens, the response time climbs to more than 1 minute.

After debugging, we identified that the delay is due to a query, where SQL server is taking too long to handle. Running the same query, at the same time, from within SSMS returns at the expected speed. Upon restarting the faulty proccess, the problem still persists. When we restart the SQL Server service, everything goes back to normal, but this action creates side-effects that we want to avoid.

We do not know how to investigate the issue further. It does not seem to be related to locked tables because eventually the query results are returned and, the same query behaves normally if run from a different proccess. Furthermore, we cannot recreate the problem. It happens randomly. We need a list of possible causes, so we can validate them whenever the problem arises again.

Comment: Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html , you should post the query, execution plans, the table(s) definitions, indexes ...

Comment: It can still be a locking issue, but more likely I'd guess it's a poor execution plan being generated for that specific client which can result from a number of things including their connection settings. Parameter sniffing causing the poor execution plan could be a possibility too. Regardless, see Sabin's comment above on how to further debug / get help with this issue.